# How to count only events that happen more than once in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a dataset of users and various actions they take with a subscription. I want to count the number of users that 'Purchase' for the second or more times.  For example:

| user_id | created_ts | action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 10/1/2023 | purchase |
| 123 | 10/2/2023 | purchase |
| 789 | 10/1/2023 | purchase |

Expected outcome:

| user_id | created_ts | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 10/2/2023 | 1 |

I only want to count the purchase when it happens more than once on the day the second or more purchase happens.

Right now, I have the below query, but it is not quite right because it is not excluding the first purchase.  Thank you in advance for any help!

```
select
    created_ts::date as date_day
    , count(distinct user_id) as reactivations
from user_subscription_history
where user_id in
    (select 
         user_id 
     from user_subscription_history where notification_type = 'Purchase'
     group by user_id
     having count(*) > 1)
group by 1
```

Comment: Use the group by where condition HAVING, like HAVING COUNT(*) > 1: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: @FrankHeikens are you proposing I add this to the main select statement? I am already utilizing having in the subquery.  I edited the query to have better formatting so this is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function for this:

**Schema (PostgreSQL v15)**

```
CREATE TABLE user_subscription_history (
  "user_id" INTEGER,
  "created_ts" TIMESTAMP,
  "action" VARCHAR(8)
);

INSERT INTO user_subscription_history
  ("user_id", "created_ts", "action")
VALUES
  ('123', '10/1/2023', 'purchase'),
  ('123', '10/2/2023', 'purchase'),
  ('789', '10/1/2023', 'purchase');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH numbered_subscriptions AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_ts)
  FROM user_subscription_history
  WHERE action = 'purchase'
)
SELECT created_ts::date as date_day
     , count(distinct user_id) as reactivations
FROM numbered_subscriptions
WHERE row_number > 1
GROUP BY 1;
```

| date_day | reactivations |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-10-02T00:00:00.000Z | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ayQFonAVaTw23fimRpZnKG/3)